# Why are my media queries not working for this specific element?

Tags: html, css, styles, media-queries

My media queries is not being applied to this one `div .col-3` although it does work for others. Is that a problem with a selector/class?

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 719px) {
 
  .col-3 {
          flex: 0 50%;
          max-width: 50%;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="row fade show">
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="ProductBox_root__13DPQ">
            <div class="ProductBox_photo__Xs8BM"><img
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/245208/pexels-photo-245208.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=3&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260"
                    alt="Aenean Ru Bristique 1" class="ProductBox_image__1ECK5">
                <div class="ProductBox_sale__1WcD7">sale</div>
                <div class="ProductBox_buttons__uyJNx"><a href="#" class="Button_small__2W39u">Quick View</a><a href="#"
                        class="Button_small__2W39u"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas"
                            data-icon="shopping-basket" class="svg-inline--fa fa-shopping-basket fa-w-18 " role="img"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M576 216v16c0 13.255-10.745 24-24 24h-8l-26.113 182.788C514.509 462.435 494.257 480 470.37 480H105.63c-23.887 0-44.139-17.565-47.518-41.212L32 256h-8c-13.255 0-24-10.745-24-24v-16c0-13.255 10.745-24 24-24h67.341l106.78-146.821c10.395-14.292 30.407-17.453 44.701-7.058 14.293 10.395 17.453 30.408 7.058 44.701L170.477 192h235.046L326.12 82.821c-10.395-14.292-7.234-34.306 7.059-44.701 14.291-10.395 34.306-7.235 44.701 7.058L484.659 192H552c13.255 0 24 10.745 24 24zM312 392V280c0-13.255-10.745-24-24-24s-24 10.745-24 24v112c0 13.255 10.745 24 24 24s24-10.745 24-24zm112 0V280c0-13.255-10.745-24-24-24s-24 10.745-24 24v112c0 13.255 10.745 24 24 24s24-10.745 24-24zm-224 0V280c0-13.255-10.745-24-24-24s-24 10.745-24 24v112c0 13.255 10.745 24 24 24s24-10.745 24-24z">
                            </path>
                        </svg> ADD TO CART</a></div>
            </div>
```

Let me confirm that I added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

so it must be something else.

Comment: is there a link available?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this media query is placed at the bottom of your css file. If it isn't then the properties are being overridden. Kindly inspect and check if the element's properties are being overridden in the css tab

Answer (score 0):

image is overflowing the container?

```
img{ width: 100% }
```

Comment: it is a valid point, however I'm afraid there's something else going on that affects media query.

Answer (score 0):

You could also target the div by Id

```
<div id="custom" class="col-3">


  #custom.col-3 {
      flex: 0 50%;
      max-width: 50%;
      border: 2px solid red
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brnt49je/

Comment: this file has no html, I cannot do that. This is JS file

Answer (score 0):

I decided to apply RWD by adding responsive classes to react component as follows:

```js
className='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3'>
```

This works for me, I hope someone will find this useful. Thank you for all your answers!